# Editable text Field not working with in Form

Tags: forms

[editable_text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVoTH.png)If i replace form with div it works but i don't know why it is not working with Form.[form_tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Yr7C.png)

Comment: Please include the code **inside your post** instead of a screenshot.